# Redirect to root is asked about a specific file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can i redirect all requests to index_main.php to index.php through .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "***from*** index_main.php to index.php"?

If answer is *yes* then

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/index_main\.php$ index.php [L]
```

---

**UPDATE**

To change index file, use `DirectoryIndex` directive:

```
DirectoryIndex index_main.php
```

Comment: I mean i have a page called index_main.php, i want this page to open when someone types my website url, but i want the url to appear as www.mysite.com and not www.mysite.com/index_main.php . how can that be achieved?

Comment: Oh. Updated answer.